# Find highest number in range and subtract a selected cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to find the highest number in a cell range and subtract the number from a different cell.

eg
900
1000
800
850

and subtract value in different cell

Thanks for any help

Comment: Use `MAX()` function or `LARGE()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any one `MAX()` or `LARGE()`

[image]

---

• in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=MAX(A1:A4)
```

---

Or, in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LARGE(A1:A4,1)
```

---

Read more on the said function from `Microsoft Documentations` --> **[MAX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/max-function-e0012414-9ac8-4b34-9a47-73e662c08098)** & **[LARGE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/large-function-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64)**

---

Comment: How would I complete the formula and subtract a value from another cell

Comment: @Gavin you need to use the following formula like this way. `=MAX(A1:A4)-another_cell_reference#`. Also have you reviewed your other posts answer

Comment: Yes thank you for your help!  How do i show the difference between  2 numbers as a negative using this formula =MAX($E$9:$E$13)-E9   eg. MAX=1000 E9=900 i want to show the difference as -100 rather than just 100

Comment: @Gavin to show that you can use `=-(MAX($E$9:$E$13)-E9)` bt i am curious to know why  do you want to do that, Or you could do the reverse instead. `=E9-MAX($E$9:$E$13)`

Comment: just to show how much less it is than the highest amount

Comment: Ah okay. Hope you have followed one of the either.